# socket.io - emited objects from server lose their functions and name once received by client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Once the player connects, the server emits a message called "playerNumber" which carries the data of all players (players are stored in objects, and all those objects are stored into an array called "allPlayers"), and their player numbers.

Once this is received by the client, the objects mysteriously lose their name ("Blob" now is called "Object") and they lose all their functions too.

Any ideas to why this has happened?

Comment: They need to be explicitly serialized. By default an object's conversion to a string is something that of `[Object]`

Comment: how would one serialize their objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need to see your ACTUAL code in order to suggest specific code to solve this problem.

Generically, you have to serialize an object yourself (into a string) before sending it over socket.io.  Javascript can't send live objects over TCP to another computer.  Instead, you have to create a binary or string representation of the object, then send that, then on the receiving end you reconstruct the desired object from the serialized representation.  Javascript does not have a built-in mechanism for doing this automatically.

One tool that is commonly used is `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.  `JSON.stringify()` will take a plain object and serialize the enumerable properties in a string.  `JSON.parse()` will take a serialized JSON string and parse it back into a plain object.

But, if your object is some sort of custom object with custom methods, then you will have to add that part of the reconstruction yourself because the object JSON methods only handle plain objects.  Usually, what I do in this case is I don't attempt to serialize the whole object.  Instead, I determine what exact pieces of data need to be sent to the other host, extra those into some string form, send that, parse that on the other end, create the desired type of object and then initialize it with the data that was sent.

Comment: despite stringifying the code, the string that results still does not contain the functions

Comment: @Canatron - Yes, stringifying does not send functions - by default, they are not enumerable properties and usually you don't want to send code with every object anyway - that's wasteful to send all the function code with every object.  That's just not how one usually does this type of thing and isn't how Javascript serializing works. You serialize and send the data. You then create the right type of object (with appropriate methods already attached) on the receiving side and give it the data you received and get exactly what you want, the right type of object initialized with the desired data.

Comment: so you are saying that the constructor function should be present in both server and client, and use the basic information of the server object to construct an object using the client-side constructor function?

Comment: @Canatron - Yes, the object definition, constructor and all appropriate methods should exist in both client and server.  Sometimes you might have some different objects in the server implementation vs. the client implementation (which is fine), but the common ones you want to use in both places need to exist in both places.  Usually, you just share the object definition in a common, shared file that both client and server use.